# HTML and JS : image to another image onclick + sound

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio

i'm trying to create a script so that when you click on the picture A, the picture B appears instead and when you click again the image A appears, etc.
It works just fine but i'd like to add to it a music when you click on the picture A so that it plays when the picture B is displayed.

```js
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/belle-for%C3%AAt-tropicale-%C3%A0-l-itin%C3%A9raire-am%C3%A9nag%C3%A9-pour-amateurs-de-la-nature-de-ka-d-ang-36703721.jpg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img alt="" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg" style="height: 85px; width: 198px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that audio and video must be muted as per browser permission rules since 2018.

In other words you can't play sounds unless the user clicks the player.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#web-audio

But you probably don’t want to have a visible audio player and to just play the music as you please, but you can't unless its visible and muted...

```
<audio controls muted></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

Here I updated your code, I used the `HTML5` audio element and on the `changeImage` function I play the sound file on every image change.

```js
function changeImage() {
    var imgElement = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    var musicElement = document.getElementById("music");
    if (imgElement.src == "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg") {
      imgElement.src = "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/belle-for%C3%AAt-tropicale-%C3%A0-l-itin%C3%A9raire-am%C3%A9nag%C3%A9-pour-amateurs-de-la-nature-de-ka-d-ang-36703721.jpg";
    } else {
      imgElement.src = "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg";
    }
    musicElement.currentTime = 0;
    musicElement.play();
  }
```

```html
<audio id="music" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg"></audio>
<p>
  <img alt="" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg" style="height: 85px; width: 198px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking this. I hope my answer will help you to reach your desired output.

[Kindly check my code on codepen.](https://codepen.io/ravishg221/pen/zYJaYVq)

```
var img1Url =
"https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg";

var img2Url =
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/belle-for%C3%AAt-tropicale-%C3%A0-l-itin%C3%A9raire-am%C3%A9nag%C3%A9-pour-amateurs-de-la-nature-de-ka-d-ang-36703721.jpg";

var audio1 = "https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-15s.mp3";

var audio2 = "https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-3s.mp3";

var imgElement = document.getElementById("my-image");

var avEl = document.createElement("audio");

function changeImage() {
console.log(avEl);
if (imgElement.src === img1Url) {
    imgElement.src = img2Url;
    playAudio(audio1);
} else {
    console.log("img2");
    imgElement.src = img1Url;
    playAudio(audio2);
}
}

function playAudio(audio) {
if(avEl){avEl.pause()}
avEl.src = audio;
avEl.play();
}
```